# How do I print without space or newline?

Tags: python

In Python2.7

I would like to print my phrase like "THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE" instead of

"T H I S  I S  H O W  I T  S H O U L D  L O O K  L I K E"

How do I do it?

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: What is your input / current code?

Comment: BTW, you probably mean "this is what it should look like" or "this is how it should look". See the question, ["Is it 'what it looks like' or 'how it looks like'?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55672/is-it-what-it-looks-like-or-how-it-looks-like)

Comment: You're probably adding commas in your print statement.

Comment: Use `print "THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE"` instead of `print "T H I S I S H O W I T S H O U L D L O O K L I K E"`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing something like this:

```
letters = "THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE"

for letter in letters:
    print letter,
```

Which will put a space between each letter during printing.

Instead of printing each letter one at a time, print the string itself.

```
>>>print letters
THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE
```

If `letters` is a list of characters and not a string, convert it into a string using `join`.

```
print "".join(letters)
```

If you can't get the letters all in one list for whatever reason, you can use `sys.stdout.write` to print strings without the trailing space or newline.

```
import sys
letters = "THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE"

for letter in letters:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
```

Result:

```
THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE
```

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work, on account of the spaces already existing in the string. It'll print `T_H_I_S__I_S[...]`, with two spaces in between the two words instead of one

Comment: The first code block in this post is not a solution. It is what I am guessing the OP's non-working code is.